# How to extend Ninject Binding Syntax

Tags: ninject

is there a way to extend the existing binding syntax (e.g. extension method) that will allow us to have something like this:

```
Bind<IRepository>().ToProvider<MyProvider<MyRepository>>().WhenCustom<SomeType>()
```

Comment: I normally use  Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(MyRepository<>)); how would you like this binding to happen

Comment: What is `WhenCustom` supposed to do? Can you give (either example or explain in prose) positive and negative cases that your condition should be including and excluding.

Answer (score 2):

Write an extension method for `IBindingWhenSyntax<T>` and use the existing `When` overload to implement your logic:

```
class BindingWhenExtensions
{
   public IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> WhenCustom<T>(
       this IBindingWhenSyntax<T> syntax)
   { 
        return syntax.When(r => true); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry that I didn't get back to this earlier, here is the example of what I need - In the Ninject there is a WhenInjectedInto method so I need something similar to this, I need to be able to get the standard syntax but also the get the custom type e.g. `code`IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> WhenInjectedInto<TParent>()`code`. The main problem here is that I need to create it with extension method and then I'm not able to get to the T type because of the TParent. At the moment I use <T, TParent> syntax and it's not so readable. Is there another way ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reframing the question (to align with your comment) you want to create an extension with a signature similar to the following;

```
public static IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> WhenCustom<TParent>(
            this IBindingWhenSyntax<T> binding)
```

As far as I can tell we're not able to extend as cleanly as this with Ninject because as you rightly allude to `T` here is defined [on an interface](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/005e6f9e38414a38ae7c6aaf346c74ec64212609/src/Ninject/Syntax/IBindingWhenSyntax.cs) that our extension doesn't know about.

So our extension signature must be;

```
public static IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> WhenCustom<T>(
            this IBindingWhenSyntax<T> binding)
```

At this point the only way I see us being able to successfully pass `TParent` is to drop the generic parameter and pass it as a standard type parameter (or pass several types);

```
 public static IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> WhenCustom(
            this IBindingWhenSyntax<T> binding, params Type[] parents)
```

This is still consistent with Ninjects own binding syntax methods;

```
/// <summary>
/// Indicates that the binding should be used only for injections on the specified types.
/// Types that derive from one of the specified types are considered as valid targets.
/// Should match at lease one of the targets.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="parents">The types to match.</param>
/// <returns>The fluent syntax.</returns>
IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> WhenInjectedInto(params Type[] parents);
```

It's just unfortunate that we don't have the luxury of extending with 'pure' generics.