# Contextual / Conditional dependency injection with depth greater than 1 with Ninject?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-2

I have a `IDataContext` interface implemented by a `InMemoryDataContext` and `MyApplicationDataContext`. This is consumed by all of my repositories which are defined as `BananaRepository : IBananaRepository` and take the data context in their constructor:

```
interface IDataContext {}
class InMemoryDataContext : IDataContext {}
class MyApplicationDataContext : IDataContext {}

interface IBananaRepository {}
class BananaRepository : IBananaRepository 
{
    public BananaRepository(IDataContext dataContext) {}
}
```

So far my consumers of the interfaces and services are ASP.NET MVC controllers, synchronous commands and queries. NInject is configured in my Web project and `IDataContext` is bound to `MyApplicationDataContext` with `InRequestScope()`.

```
 kernel.Bind<IDataContext>().To<MyApplicationDataContext>().InRequestScope();
 kernel.Bind<IBananaRepository>().To<BananaRepository>();
```

I have reached the point in the evolution of my project where I want to start adding asynchronous processing (commands, events+handlers, etc). The problem I am facing is that for those I need to get a transient `IDataContext` (new one each time) but the binding is already set-up for a `IDataContext` instance per request for my controllers.

Consider this simple scenario, where my `DoSomethingAsyncCommand` will execute on a new thread:

```
class DoSomethingAsyncCommand : IAsyncCommand<TArgs>
{
    public DoSomethingAsyncCommand(IBananaRepository repository) {}

    public bool Execute(TArgs args) {}
}
```

I want when NInject instantiates a class implementations of `IAsyncCommand` the `IBananaRepository` (and all my other repositories) to be initialized with a new instance of `IDataContext` rather than the one for the web request to be reused (effectively I want for `IAsyncCommand` my `IDataContext` to be bound as `InTransientScope()`)

How can I do that?

P.S: I am using the CommonServiceLocator rather than the Ninject kernel directly to instantiate IAsyncCommand instances.

Comment: Won't just a simple "kernel.Bind<IDataContext>().To<MyApplicationDataContext>().WhenInjectedInto<IAsyncCommand >().InTransientScope();" binding do?

Comment: @Hari No, because the context is injected in the repository not in the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at https://github.com/ninject/ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Planning/Bindings/BindingConfigurationBuilder.cs

There you find IsAnyAnchestorNamed. You can use that same loop and combine it with the condition you find in WhenInjectedInto and call it from a [custom When](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207601/how-to-extend-ninject-binding-syntax/10228638#10228638).

Comment: Thanks - I will look at implementing this later today and will get back to you (and this question/answer).

Comment: Hm. So if I make this work and have `pbulic DoSomethingAsyncCommand(IRepo1 repo1, IRepo2 repo2)` and I use `TransientScope` it would effectively end up creating two `IDataContext` instances? How do I get around that?

Comment: Is it just me or what I am thinking won't be possible, because when the data context is being instantiated there is no reference to the repository nor to the command to use as a scope object? I think I might be better off using a Factory in my scenario?

Comment: You can use your command as scope using the named scope extension.